# Error when "sudo apt update"

Tags: apt

I was trying to run the command `sudo apt update`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt update
    E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list (Suite)
    E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How can I fix this?

I checked the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list` and is a text file containing only the following line:

`deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_17.10/`

Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? 17.10 is End-of-Life sibce a long time ago. The error is obvious: It refers to an old repository for Lutris that no longer exists (such format is used now exclusively for Debian. For Ubuntu they have a proper PPA at Launchpad: https://lutris.net/downloads/

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 or the 2017-October release is EOL (*end-of-life*). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/19/ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark-end-of-life-reached-on-july-19-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)